Errors implementing CryptoJS AES ECB Decryption in Rust
I need to translate my decryption code from JS into Rust.
Here's the JS example code.
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

const key = "KeyIs16CharsLong";
const value = "Hello, Rust!";

const keyParsed = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);

// Encryption
const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, keyParsed, {
mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
}).toString();

console.log(key); // 'KeyIs16CharsLong'
console.log(encrypted); // 'nFWwLNMi2toxug1hDb/HGg=='

// Decryption (this part needs to be implemented in Rust)
const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, keyParsed, {
mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log("Decrypted:", decrypted); // Decrypted: Hello, Rust!

The example output:
key: 'KeyIs16CharsLong'
encrypted value: 'nFWwLNMi2toxug1hDb/HGg=='
Now when I try to decrypt with this key and value in Rust I face problems.
I get 'value: UnpadError' or redundant 0s0s0s0s at the end of the result or the value itself is just different.
I tried a bunch of different approaches, different libraries.
Here's one attempt:
use aes::cipher::{block_padding::Pkcs7, BlockDecryptMut, BlockEncryptMut, KeyInit};
use base64::Engine;
use base64::engine::general_purpose; 

type Aes128EcbDec = ecb::Decryptor<aes::Aes128>;

fn test_decryption() {
    let key = "KeyIs16CharsLong";
    let plaintext = "nFWwLNMi2toxug1hDb/HGg==";

    // Decode key and adjust to 16 bytes
    let mut key_vec = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(key).expect("Invalid Base64 key");
    key_vec.resize(16, 0); // Pad with zeros if the decoded key is too short
    let key: [u8; 16] = key_vec.try_into().expect("Key must be 16 bytes for AES-128");

    // Convert ciphertext from hex to bytes
    let mut ciphertext = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(plaintext).expect("Invalid Base64 ciphertext");

    let pt = Aes128EcbDec::new(&key.into())
        .decrypt_padded_mut::<Pkcs7>(&mut ciphertext)
        .unwrap();

    // Convert decrypted plaintext to a string
    let decrypted_plaintext = String::from_utf8(pt.to_vec()).expect("Decryption produced invalid UTF-8");
    println!("Decrypted plaintext: {}", decrypted_plaintext);
}

This code raises:
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:30:10:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: UnpadError

At row: let pt = Aes128EcbDec::new(&key.into()).decrypt_padded_mut::<Pkcs7>(&mut ciphertext).unwrap();
cargo check returns no errors, just minor warnings.
Please, help me solve this problem. I spent so much time on it.

The key must not be Base64 decoded in the Rust code, but UTF-8 encoded as in the CryptoJS code.

Thanks to @topaco 's comment the solution is found. The code was quite close, it simply did not need the key to be decoded as Base64.
Here's the result code:
use aes::cipher::{block_padding::Pkcs7, BlockDecryptMut, KeyInit};
use base64::Engine;
use base64::engine::general_purpose;

type Aes128EcbDec = ecb::Decryptor<aes::Aes128>;
async fn test_decryption() {
    let key = "KeyIs16CharsLong";
    let plaintext = "nFWwLNMi2toxug1hDb/HGg==";

    // Decode key 
    let key_bytes = key.as_bytes();

    // Convert ciphertext from hex to bytes
    let mut ciphertext = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(plaintext).expect("Invalid Base64 ciphertext");

    let pt = Aes128EcbDec::new_from_slice(key_bytes)
        .unwrap()
        .decrypt_padded_mut::<Pkcs7>(&mut ciphertext)
        .unwrap();

    // Convert decrypted plaintext to a string
    let decrypted_plaintext = String::from_utf8(pt.to_vec()).expect("Decryption produced invalid UTF-8");
    println!("Decrypted plaintext: {}", decrypted_plaintext);
}

